# How to access 'session.conversationData' while intercepting 'send' hook from middleware?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have been following the official [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-intercept-messages) while trying to intercept user/bot messages.

```
bot.use({
  botbuilder (session, next) {
    logger.info("MESSAGE RECEIVED:" + session.message.text);
    next();
  },

  send (event, next) {
    logger.info("MESSAGE SENT:" + event.text);
    next();
  }
});
```

While `botbuilder` hook behaves as expected, `send` is never called.

At the moment when i will be able to solve this issue, my goal is to have
access to the `session` object, more precisely to the `session.conversationData` storage container from the `send` method middleware.

**What have i done ?**

i have been following the [Logging middleware example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/capability-middlewareLogging) and the readme states:

> The `botbuilder` hook on the middleware is an example of `ISessionMiddleware`. The main advantage of using this hook instead of `receive` is the access we gain to the `session`.

and

> `send` and `receive` hooks use `IEventMiddleware`. The first argument is the event itself. To see whether an event is a message, check to see if `event.type` is `'message'`.

Currently i have wrapped the `session.send` in a custom function so i can log the messages which are send by the bot, and another function which logs the user response from inside the dialog. While this solution solves my problem it feels bad ( need to manually update each dialog ) and i am not able to create a generic middleware which could be loaded from a module.

**What am i trying to achieve ?**

The purpose of my middleware is to intercept user/bot messages and log them to SQL table with the following schema : `conversation-id, message-text, timestamp`.

`conversation-id` is stored in `session.conversationData` storage container, thus why i need to get access to `session` object from the `send` hook.

using `"botbuilder": "^3.13.1"`

Comment: Take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/tree/master/Node/examples/feature-azureSql) and see if it helps you

Answer (score 3):

You can load the session within the send by calling loadSessionWithoutDispatching:

```
send: function (message, next) {
    bot.loadSessionWithoutDispatching(message.address,function (error,session){
        console.log(session.userData);
    });

    next();
}
```

Comment: @Alexander Sorry about that... I've edited my answer.

Comment: FYI This seems to load the data from the store again each time it's used rather than just accessing the already loaded data