# How to create and send a backchannel event with every message in bot framework?

Tags: node.js, hook, botframework

I'm trying to access a session variable from the botbuilder middleware in `send` hook:

```
bot.use({
    botbuilder: function (session, next) {
        session.send(); // it doesn't work without this..
        session.sendTyping();
        console.log('session.userData', session.userData['UI_Changes']);
        var reply = createEvent("UI_Changes", session.userData['UI_Changes'], session.message.address);
        session.send(reply);
        // session.userData['UI_Changes'] = {};
        next();
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        // console.log('session.userData', session.userData['UI_Changes']);
        // var reply = createEvent("UI_Changes", session.userData['UI_Changes'], session.message.address);
        // session.send(reply);
        // session.userData['UI_Changes'] = {};
        next();
    }
});
```

But since `session` is not available in `send`, how can I access the `userData`?

`createEvent` simply creates a `backchannel` event:

```
//Creates a backchannel event
const createEvent = (eventName, value, address) => {
    var msg = new builder.Message().address(address);
    msg.data.type = "event";
    msg.data.name = eventName;
    msg.data.value = value;
    return msg;
}
```

I found this answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48197096):

```
send: function (message, next) {
    bot.loadSessionWithoutDispatching(message.address,function (error,session){
        console.log(session.userData);
    });

    next();
}
```

But, when I try to create an event and send it, I'm not able to access the address

```
bot.loadSessionWithoutDispatching(event.address, function (error,session){
            console.log('session not null?', session !== null ? "yes" : "no");
            if(session !== null){
                console.log('session.userData', session.userData['UI_Changes'], 'address:', session);
                var reply = createEvent("UI_Changes", session.userData['UI_Changes'], event.address); //undefined
                session.send(reply);
                session.userData['UI_Changes'] = {};
            }
        });
```

both `session.message` and `event.address` are `undefined` inside the callback function. How can I possibly do a workaround?

`event` has following content:

```
event: { type: 'message',
  text: 'You reached the Greeting intent. You said \'hi\'.',
  locale: 'en-US',
  localTimestamp: '2018-06-21T14:37:12.684Z',
  from: { id: 'Steves@4MRN9VFFpAk', name: 'Steves' },
  recipient: { id: 'pruthvi', name: 'pruthvi' },
  inputHint: 'acceptingInput' }
```

whereas outside the `loadSessionWithoutDispatching` function it has:

```
event outside { type: 'message',
  agent: 'botbuilder',
  source: 'directline',
  textLocale: 'en-US',
  address: 
   { id: 'A7nrBS4yINt2607QtKpxOP|0000048',
     channelId: 'directline',
     user: { id: 'pruthvi', name: 'pruthvi' },
     conversation: { id: 'A7nrBS4yINt2607QtKpxOP' },
     bot: { id: 'Steves@4MRN9VFFpAk', name: 'Steves' },
     serviceUrl: 'https://directline.botframework.com/' },
  text: 'You reached the Greeting intent. You said \'hi\'.' }
```

I've used `bot.loadSession` instead of `loadSessionWithoutDispatching` and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

I've used `bot.loadSession` instead of `loadSessionWithoutDispatching` and it works fine.